# Using Roslyn for C#, how do I get a list of all properties that compose a return type?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Let's say that I have queried a single method from a collection of methods:

```
var myMethod = someListofMethods.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Identifier.ValueText == myMethodName);
```

Now I want to take the method's return type. . .

```
var returnType = myMethod.ReturnType;
```

. . .and determine (if it is not a primitive) what properties are contained within that type.

So, for example  let's say the return type is `FooObject` which is defined:

```
public class FooObject{
     public string Fizz {get; set; }
     public string Buzz {get; set; }
}
```

How do I properly interrogate `FooObject` for a list of it's properties?

Here is what I have already tried:

```
returnType.DescendantNodes().OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>();
```

But this didn't work.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking at the [abstract syntax tree (AST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) level of code. Hence line:

```
returnType.DescendantNodes().OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>();
```

returns nothing. `returnType` in this context is `IdentifierNameSyntax` node of the AST, just containing text `FooObject`. If you want to analyze return type, you should:

- interpret syntax tree from `returnType` point of view to find full namespace of the return type
- search trough code to find this type declaration
- analyze type declaration syntax tree to find all its properties

**But**, it is in fact what compiler does so you can go level up with Roslyn usage to the compilation level, for example:

```
var workspace = Workspace.LoadSolution(solutionName);
var solution = workspace.CurrentSolution;

var createCommandList = new List<ISymbol>();
var @class = solution.Projects.Select(s => s.GetCompilation()
                                            .GetTypeByMetadataName(className))
                              .FirstOrDefault();
var method = @class.GetMembers(methodName)
                    .AsList()
                    .Where(s => s.Kind == CommonSymbolKind.Method)
                    .Cast<MethodSymbol>()
                    .FirstOrDefault();
var returnType = method.ReturnType as TypeSymbol;
var returnTypeProperties = returnType.GetMembers()
                                     .AsList()
                                     .Where(s => s.Kind == SymbolKind.Property)
                                     .Select(s => s.Name);
```

Comment: Worked beautifully!  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Create the below class `CsharpClass.cs`:

```
public class CsharpClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Namespace { get; set; }

    public List<CsharpProperty> Properties { get; set; }

    public string PrimaryKeyType { get; set; }

    public class CsharpProperty
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public CsharpProperty(string name, string type)
        {
            Name = name;
            Type = type;
        }
    }

    public CsharpClass()
    {
        Properties = new List<CsharpProperty>();
    }
}
```

---

Create the below helper class `CsharpClassParser.cs`:

```
public static class CsharpClassParser
{
    public static CsharpClass Parse(string content)
    {
        var cls = new CsharpClass();
        var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(content);
        var members = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MemberDeclarationSyntax>();

        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            if (member is PropertyDeclarationSyntax property)
            {
                cls.Properties.Add(new CsharpClass.CsharpProperty(
                     property.Identifier.ValueText,
                     property.Type.ToString())
                 );
            }

            if (member is NamespaceDeclarationSyntax namespaceDeclaration)
            {
                cls.Namespace = namespaceDeclaration.Name.ToString();
            }

            if (member is ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration)
            {
                cls.Name = classDeclaration.Identifier.ValueText;

                cls.PrimaryKeyType = FindPrimaryKeyType(classDeclaration);
            }

            //if (member is MethodDeclarationSyntax method)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("Method: " + method.Identifier.ValueText);
            //}
        }


        return cls;
    }

    private static string FindPrimaryKeyType(ClassDeclarationSyntax classDeclaration)
    {
        if (classDeclaration == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (classDeclaration.BaseList == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        foreach (var baseClass in classDeclaration.BaseList.Types)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(baseClass.Type.ToString(), @"<(.*?)>");
            if (match.Success)
            {
                var primaryKey = match.Groups[1].Value;

                if (AppConsts.PrimaryKeyTypes.Any(x => x.Value == primaryKey))
                {
                    return primaryKey;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**How to use?**

Read the content of the class as string and pass it to `CsharpClassParser.Parse()`

```
const string content = @"
namespace Acme.Airlines.AirCraft
{
    public class AirCraft
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual int Code { get; set; }

        public AirCraft()
        {

        }
    }
}";

var csharpClass = CsharpClassParser.Parse(content);

Console.WriteLine(csharpClass.Name);
Console.WriteLine(csharpClass.Namespace);
Console.WriteLine(csharpClass.Properties.Count);
```