# VSIX / Roslyn - How do I monitor open solution for any classes derived from MyClass

Tags: c#, vsix

Hi I need to write a VSIX extension which will monitor the classes currently defined in the open solution. It will look for any classes derived from MyClass and automatically generate source code for a stub class based on properties defined in the matching class. It will then create a new c# file postfix it with autogen.cs and then update the project to add the new file to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

- Use CodeAnalysis to find all inheritances for MyClass: [Finding all class declarations than inherit from another with Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234052/finding-all-class-declarations-than-inherit-from-another-with-roslyn)
- Use CodeAnalysis to get properties from matching class: [Class Members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316952/using-roslyn-for-c-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-properties-that-compose-a-return)
- Create C# file using CodeAnalysis: [Roslyn.CodeGeneration](https://gist.github.com/cmendible/9b8c7d7598f1ab0bc7ab5d24b2622622)
- Add file to project: [Include a folder and files in the Project using VSIX](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/13b1de8a-4df1-4be6-aa97-4a8c0b38a986/include-a-folder-and-files-in-the-project-using-vsix?forum=vsx)